# Why am I not able to read variable from json output from my php in my controller when it succeeds in angularjs application?

Tags: javascript, php, json, angularjs

```
 $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'api/userBadgeIdRound.php',
                data: { 'idUser': $scope.idUser },
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;  charset=iso-8859-1' }
            })
            .success(function (data, status) {
                console.log(data);
                //$scope.messages = JSON.stringify(data);
                $scope.userBadges = data.badges;
                $scope.idRound = data.round.idRound;
                console.log($scope.userBadges);
                console.log($scope.idRound);
            })
            .error(function (data, status) {
                console.log("post errore");
            });
```

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'idRound' of undefined
    at controller.js:503
    at angular.js:7976
    at deferred.promise.then.wrappedCallback (angular.js:11408)
    at deferred.promise.then.wrappedCallback (angular.js:11408)
    at angular.js:11494
    at Scope.$eval (angular.js:12518)
    at Scope.$digest (angular.js:12330)
    at Scope.$apply (angular.js:12622)
    at done (angular.js:8234)
    at completeRequest (angular.js:8439)

 console.log(data); with this i am able to get json data from  php file but
```

Array�����������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������
��������������������(this is output from my php)

```
 console.log($scope.userBadges);

 console.log($scope.idRound);

output(undefined)
```

I am unable to assign while assigning it's showing error like undefined and I found one thing to solve to this kind of problem from [here](http://blog.salientdigital.com/2009/06/06/special-characters-showing-up-as-a-question-mark-inside-of-a-black-diamond/)  so I changed my
charset from UTF-8 to iso-8859-1. However, in my case it's not working.

Comment: And you are sure that you in the AJAx have said it's json? and in the PHP that the return type is json?

Comment: `$scope.round.idRound`? and you'll never get `userBadges`, since you have only `badges` inside the json.

Comment: what is "Array" ? shouldn't be there. how do you output the data in the PHP?

Comment: yes you are right @Marc B now i am talking about $scope.round.idRound this one i am getting and inserted in db but while i am passing to other variable its showing undefined yes kasper Franz  i am encoded json  with this function json_encode($json); in php like  this

Comment: Your php output might not be a valid json string. You should make sure you output nothing except the json_encode'd string and that your content type is "application/json".

Comment: the same code is working in my other server but while i am running it in azure microsoft web matrix its showing error like this @galc hen and i am new to web matrix and angularjs can any one give me some hint to solve

Comment: look in the web developer tools - network tab to see the output you are getting back from the server. I would guess that it's not a valid json string, and if so - you need to fix it on the server side

Comment: hi guyz i found one thing that in firefox browser i am getting json response like this  Array������������������������������������� can i any one help me i did not know why i am response coming like this from my php file in azure microsoft web marix

Comment: What language is your output in?

Comment: i am calling from angularjs controller with http method to get json data from php file using mysql @Tom It's in English

Comment: @SaidaRao No, I mean your return, your json, the data inside it, what language is it in? English, Chinese, Korean etc